# Expression statement is not assignment or call warning in Javascript code

Tags: javascript

Switched from Atom code editor to PHP Storm, and a lot of my code is being highlighted when I use promises with the following message: `Expression statement is not assignment or call`

Here is an example of some highlighted code:

```js
getTickers.bitfinex = function() {
  var counter = 0,
    promises = []

//highlighted code begins here
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      request.get({
          url: 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/symbols'
        },
        function(err, res, body) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, 'bitfinex api error')
            reject(err, 'bitfinex api error')
          }
          if (!err) {
            body = JSON.parse(body)
            var symbols = []

            body.forEach(function(symbol) {
              symbol = 't' + symbol.toUpperCase()
              symbols.push(symbol)
            })
            resolve(symbols)
          }
        })
    })
    .then((symbols) => {
      var symbolsStr = symbols.join()
      request.get({
          url: 'https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/tickers?symbols=' + symbolsStr
        },
        function(err, res, body) {
          body = JSON.parse(body)
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, 'bitfinex api error')
          }
          if (body[0] == 'error') {
            console.log(body, 'bitfinex api error')
          }
          if (body[0] !== 'error') {
            body.forEach(function(ticker) {
              var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var currencyPair = ticker[0].replace("t", ""),
                  splitCurrencies = currencyPair.match(/[A-Z]{3}/g),
                  baseCurrency = splitCurrencies[0],
                  quoteCurrency = splitCurrencies[1]
                Ticker.create({
                  currency_pair: baseCurrency + '-' + quoteCurrency,
                  base_currency: baseCurrency,
                  quote_currency: quoteCurrency,
                  last: ticker[7],
                  volume: ticker[8],
                  native_currency_pair: ticker[0],
                  exchange: 'bitfinex',
                  time: new Date().getTime()
                }, function(err, document) {
                  if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                  }
                  if (document) {
                    counter++
                    resolve()
                  }
                })

              })
              promises.push(promise)
            })
            Promise.all(promises)
              .then(() => console.log(counter + ' bitfinex tickers updated'))
              .catch((err) => console.log(err, 'bitfinex update error'))
          }
        })
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
//highlight ends here
}
```

What can I add or change in the code to make this correct so the warning goes away?

Comment: Can you show us the complete highlighted code, please? Especially beginning and end. The parts you've shown *are* assignments or calls.

Comment: Are you sure there are no syntax errors? Maybe your editor is confused because of the omitted semicolons.

Comment: @Bergi Actually that was the complete highlighted portion, but when I removed the only semicolon in the code, the highlighted section became much bigger. Will update now

Comment: You should report it as a bug, the code is fine. My guess is it has to do with the call expression starting with a `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to disable this WebStorm-specific code inspection go to

***WebStorm*** -> ***Preferences*** -> **Editor** -> **Inspections**

and uncheck the box under ***JavaScript*** -> **JavaScript validity issues**

that has the label, "expression statement which is not assignment or call".

[image]

If you would like to actually change your code to fix these errors, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114991/can-someone-explan-this-error-expression-statement-is-not-assignment-or-call).